# Como recarregar uma página com load.gif?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Caros, como faço para a página recarregar de forma com que não "pisque"? Eu posso deixar um GIF na tela enquanto a página é recarregada?

```
    $('#objetivos-form').live('submit',function(){

        var form = $(this);
        // validando
        if (             
            form.find('input[name="objetivo[]"]:checked').val() == '' ||        
            form.find('input[name="objetivo[]"]:checked').val() == null      
        ){
            message.erro('Escolha um objetivo!', '#result');                

        } else {

            $.post( form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result){
                $(".descubra-objetivo").fadeOut();                   
                // location.reload();

                $(".descubra-alterar").fadeIn();
            });
        }    
        return false; 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, sugiro que siga esse tutorial, mesmo ele estando em inglês é bastante esclarecedor, segue o link.: http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, Luis Fernando. Consegui implementar com a sua dica e já atende a minha necessidade. Obrigado também @Sergio.

Answer (score 1):

A unica maneira de garantir que uma página não pisca ou não mostra-e-esconde conteudo (por causa do javascript não ser imediato) é via CSS.

Todo o conteúdo que vai ser alterado por CSS "imediatamente", ou seja no `onLoad` ou `DOMready` da página não tem outra maneira de garantir comportamento senão via CSS.

Assim a sugestão é ter `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, ou `opacity: 0` e mudar via javascript quando a página abrir.

Para além do que escreví em cima, todas as alterações que forem feitas numa página (no lado do cliente) tudo é perdido quando a página é carregada novamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Sergio. O problema é que sou obrigado a recarregar a página pois há um pequeno trecho de código PHP onde ele faz uma consulta por metadados e exibe na página.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, pode carregar dados via ajax sem ter de recarregar a página. Sabia isso?

Comment: Sim, @Sergio. É que estou procurando algumas alternativas para o que estou precisando. Estou utilizando o framework [http://elgg.org/] Elgg e testando as possibilidades.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade eu respondi em resposta à informação que colocou na pergunta. Se tem um outro problema ou um problema mais específico coloque isso na pergunta ou crie nova pergunta. Pelo link que me mandou parece-me que uma solução de reload parcial da página (ajax) é o ideal.